# How to match all the triggers with zabbix api and java

Tags: java, zabbix

I need to get all the triggers from my Zabbix Dashboard. So if there is a trigger, doesn't matter which severity, I need to get this. Here is a screenshot of the trigger dashboard with one entry:
[image] *click on it to watch it bigger*
So if there are no active triggers, this list is empty.

What I've already:

```
jsonObj.put("method", "trigger.get");
        // Priority: 0 = Not classified | 1 = Information | 2 = Warning | 3 =
        // Average | 4 = High | 5 = Disaster
        jsonObj.put(
                "params",
                (new JSONObject().put(
                        "filter",
                        new JSONObject().put("priority", 1).put("group", "WZU-Server")).put(
                        "output", "extend")));
```

But this returns me a lot of old triggers, which aren't active anymore. I really only need the triggers, which are displayed on the dashboard!

How can I achieve this? I don't get it for hours with the zabbix api...

INFO:
The group ID is 7
There are different hosts in this group
If a trigger has the status OK, I don't need it. Only if there is a PROBLEM.

**Edit**
I'm really close to my target.
My current code looks like this:

```
int count = 2;
while (count <= 5){
    jsonObj.put("jsonrpc", "2.0");
    jsonObj.put("method", "trigger.get");
    // Value: 0 = OK | 1 = PROBLEM | 2 = UNKNOWN
    // Priority: 0 = Not classified | 1 = Information | 2 = Warning | 3 =
    // Average | 4 = High | 5 = Disaster

    // count = priority. It start with two and end with 5
    jsonObj.put("params", (new JSONObject().put("filter", new JSONObject().put("priority", count).put("group", "WZU-Server").put("value", 1)).put("output", "extend")));
    jsonObj.put("id", 0);
    jsonObj.put("auth", "8ba6b9f29dd68e0c98cdea9ee01f2614");

    putMethod.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(jsonObj.toString(), "application/json", "UTF-8"));
}
```

At this time, my dashboard is empty. So I shouldn't get any Objects of this code.
"Warning" is empty, so it is okay.
"Average returns 8 Objects. All of the objects are older than a week. Bad!
"High" is empty, so it is okay.
"Disaster" returns 1 Objects. This object is over one week old. Bad!

So how can I achieve that I only get the entrys of my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an external application that calls zabbix API to check statuses.

There is no such thing as "status of the systems". If by "systems" you mean "hosts". In zabbix  you have *hosts* that have monitored *items*. Items are constantly getting values that are saved into *history*. The data received passes *triggers* mechanisms that can raise *alerts*.

Now, what you mention that you see in dashboard is probably a mix of a host availability statuses and alerts. Let us call the whole picture you see in the dashboard "system health". To understand the system health you may want:

- Check if there are any hosts  with unavailable agent, that's it, hosts you monitor with zabbix agent installed and zabbix server can't reach the agent. To do that you can use [host.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/host/get) with filter on "available" property.
- Check if there are any alerts, that's it, if you use alerts, this is the simplest way to get the red stuff from the dashboard. you can do that with [alert.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/alert/get). I've never used it, so check if you need any filters there to get active alerts.
- Probably you can also check events coming from triggers using [event.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/event/get) but I've never used this method either.
- What works for me and what you may be forced to do if you have agentless hosts without alerts in the system health, is checking specific items history. To do it you need to use [history.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/history/get) to get the values, usually last N values or values for the last N minutes, which you can analyze in your code. This approach probably moves the monitoring and alerting purpose from zabbix to your app leaving zabbix server to only to gather the data.

Just keep experimenting, but read how zabbix works and what the concepts are first. The knowledge of the platform will save you lots of time that you'd better invest in writing code.

Comment: Thanks, I found now "trigger" and experimenting with it. But i've a question. For example when I add the param "active", and I will set it to true (so only active triggers should come), how can I do that? I only can insert integer. So I tried with 0 (false) and 1 (true), but nothing changed

Comment: @LongJohn: Aren't these triggers you are looking for? When yes, take a look to the trigger.get() of the API

Comment: @LongJohn , I think "active" is not what you are after. You want to filter on "value":1, which means "has problem now". "active" means the trigger is actively waiting to be triggered.

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky: When I click on "triggers" on my zabbix website, then I see, if there are errors. If not, the list is empty. And exactly that I will in my program. But when I will get all the triggers of the displayed group, I get over 2000 triggers!
I updated my question to match my new question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LongJohn did you try with "value":1 ? you are not the first to get into this. Search zabbix forums for trigger api get active. You'll see how it is done.

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky: Yes, but I get also very old Problems. Okay, I'll try my luck there

Comment: @LongJohn check this https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/MoZBX , the app uses API to get data from zabbix and you can see if it does what you want here http://www.mozbx.net/start.html , if it does, learn from his code how to do that.

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky: Thanks for the link, but sadly, this won't work. The zabbix runs in our intranet of the company, so it can't reach it. But I'm now really close to my targe. I'll update my question.

Comment: It works now. Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer to give you some rep.